# Trying to manually unwind the callstack using asm and stackdump

Tags: c, arm, embedded, callstack

I have some stack dump, an elf with debug symbols as well as the original source code. Since this code runs in an embedded environment, and we cannot connect JTAG, the only information we have is the stack dump which is produced by the hard fault handler. I'm trying to reconstruct the callstack from the dump, but something here doesn't add up. Code is running on ARM Cortex M4.

## The real callstack:

```
Example of a crashing function
time_t calcCurrentTime(void) ->
    uint32_t calcDiff(void) ->
        void voidFunction(void) ->
            void voidFunctionWith1Param(int param) -> 
                int intFunction(void) -> 
                    int intFunctionWithParam(int param) -> 
                        void crashingFunction(void) -> 
                            (*nullPtrFunction)(void)()
```

## The stack:

On the left, the stack address, on the right the value at that address.

```
0xc0e1fe8 0x0000002b, r0
0xc0e1fec 0x0000000a, r1
0xc0e1ff0 0x00026390, r2
0xc0e1ff4 0x00000000, r3
0xc0e1ff8 0x77dd6416, r12
0xc0e1ffc 0x18e1877b, lr
0xc0e2000 0x00000000, pc
0xc0e2004 0x60000000, xpsr
0xc0e2008 0x12000000
0xc0e200c 0x18e18793, lr to crashingFunction
0xc0e2010 0x0000014e
0xc0e2014 0x18e187ab, lr to intFunctionWithParam
0xc0e2018 0x12000000
0xc0e201c 0x18e187c1, lr to intFunction
0xc0e2020 0x12000000
0xc0e2024 0x18e187e3, lr to voidFunctionWith1Param
0xc0e2028 0x00000000
0xc0e202c 0x18e18811, lr to voidFunction
0xc0e2030 0x00000000
0xc0e2034 0x00022d68
0xc0e2038 0x00000000
0xc0e203c 0x18e18837, lr to calcDiff
0xc0e2040 0x00000000
0xc0e2044 0x18e4f899
0xc0e2048 0x00022d68
0xc0e204c 0x00000000
0xc0e2050 0x18e6b00c
0xc0e2054 0x00022d68
0xc0e2058 0x18e0f529, lr to whoever called calcCurrentTime
...
```

## The assembly:

```
========   void __stdcall crashingFunction(void)   ========
    
    18e18768 08 b5           push       { r3, lr }
    18e1876a 04 48           ldr        r0, "Entered crashingFunction\r\n"
    18e1876c 44 f0 58 f8     bl         iprintf
    18e18770 03 48           ldr        r0, "About to execute crashing func\r\n"

    18e18772 44 f0 55 f8     bl         iprintf
    18e18776 00 23           movs       r3,#0x0
    18e18778 98 47           blx        r3
    18e1877a 08 bd           pop        { r3, pc }
    
========   int __stdcall intFunctionWithParam(int param)   ========

    18e18784 10 b5           push       { r4, lr }
    18e18786 04 46           mov        r4,r0
    18e18788 03 48           ldr        r0, "Entered intFunctionWithParam\r\n"

    18e1878a 44 f0 49 f8     bl         iprintf
    18e1878e ff f7 eb ff     bl         crashingFunction
    18e18792 60 1d           adds       r0,r4,#0x5
    18e18794 10 bd           pop        { r4, pc }
    
========   int __stdcall intFunction(void)   ========
                             
    18e1879c 10 b5           push       { r4, lr }
    18e1879e 84 b0           sub        sp,#0x10
    18e187a0 0d 48           ldr        r0, "Entered intFunction\r\n"
    18e187a2 44 f0 3d f8     bl         iprintf
    18e187a6 02 23           movs       r3,#0x2
    18e187a8 01 93           str        r3,[sp,#arr[0]]
    18e187aa 05 23           movs       r3,#0x5
    18e187ac 02 93           str        r3,[sp,#arr[1]]
    18e187ae 01 20           movs       r0,#0x1
    18e187b0 ff f7 e8 ff     bl         intFunctionWithParam
    18e187b4 03 90           str        r0,[sp,#arr[2]]
    18e187b6 00 24           movs       r4,#0x0
    18e187b8 08 e0           b          loopEnd
loopStart:
    18e187ba 04 ab           add        r3,sp,#0x10
    18e187bc 03 eb 84 03     add.w      r3,r3,r4, lsl #0x2
    18e187c0 53 f8 0c 1c     ldr.w      r1,[r3,#-0xc]
    18e187c4 05 48           ldr        r0, "Got value: %d"

    18e187c6 44 f0 2b f8     bl         iprintf
    18e187ca 01 34           adds       r4,#0x1
loopEnd:
    18e187cc 02 2c           cmp        r4,#0x2
    18e187ce f4 dd           ble        loopStart
    18e187d0 0a 20           movs       r0,#0xa
    18e187d2 04 b0           add        sp,#0x10
    18e187d4 10 bd           pop        { r4, pc }

========   void __stdcall voidFunctionWith1Param(int param)   ========

    18e187e0 08 b5           push       { r3, lr }
    18e187e2 05 48           ldr        r0, "Entered voidFunctionWith1Param\r\n"
    
    18e187e4 44 f0 1c f8     bl         iprintf
    18e187e8 ff f7 d8 ff     bl         intFunction 
    18e187ec 01 46           mov        r1,r0
    18e187ee 03 48           ldr        r0, "Result from a is %d\r\n"
    
    18e187f0 44 f0 16 f8     bl         iprintf
    18e187f4 08 bd           pop        { r3, pc }


========   void __stdcall voidFunction(void)   ========

    18e18800    push       { r3, lr }
    18e18802    ldr        r0, "Entered voidFunction\r\n"
    
    18e18804    bl         iprintf
    18e18808    movs       r0,#0x1
    18e1880a    bl         voidFunctionWith1Param
    18e1880e    ldr        r0, "Done!"
    
    18e18810    bl         iprintf
    18e18814    pop        { r3, pc }

========   uint __stdcall calcDiff(void)   ========

    18e18820 38 b5           push       { r3, r4, r5, lr }
    18e18822 e8 f7 e7 ff     bl         notRelatedFunc             ; Saves milliseconds to r3
    18e18826 0a 4d           ldr        r5,[0x18e18850]            ; r5 = 1000
    18e18828 a5 fb 00 30     umull      r3,r0,r5,r0
    18e1882c 84 09           lsrs       r4,r0,#0x6                 ; miliseconds / 1000
    18e1882e 09 4b           ldr        r3,[0x18e18854]            
    18e18830 18 68           ldr        r0,[r3,#0x0]               ; globalVariable
    18e18832 a5 fb 00 30     umull      r3,r0,r5,r0                
    18e18836 85 09           lsrs       r5,r0,#0x6                 ; globalVariable / 1000
    18e18838 ff f7 e2 ff     bl         voidFunction
    18e1883c ac 42           cmp        r4,r5
    18e1883e 05 d8           bhi        notRelatedFunc2
    ...
```

## The questions:

1. LR to `calcCurrentTime` was lost. How is this possible?
2. To get to the next LR from `0xc0e202c` we had to add 16, not 8. Despite `voidFunction` being the most unremarkable function of the bunch. It has no variables defined on the stack. So why is there such a gap in the stack?
3. I'm trying to figure out the rules in order to manually unwind the call stack.

Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, the call stack doesn’t seem to match up perfectly with your binary. The first lr 0x18e1877b and next lr 0x18e18793 look fine - they both point to the instruction after the blx/bl. But the third lr 0x18e187ab looks off - based on the code I’d expect 0x18e187b5. Are you certain you’re looking at the right binary?

Comment: Yes, I've verified that this is indeed the right binary. Is it possible that the stack got corrupted somehow during the hard fault?

Comment: It depends on the bug, of course. It's definitely possible if you have something scribbling on stack memory, but I'd normally expect the stack to be in much worse shape.

Comment: How large is your stack, where does it begin and where does it end? Could it per chance be 8kb = 0x2000 large?

Comment: @Lundin it is 8kb, you're right

Comment: ...where does it begin and where does it end... do you have a stack overflow or not...

Comment: I don't think there's a stack overflow, we fill the stack with 0xa5 to determine overflows, and I see there's still a lot of 0xa5 towards the end

Comment: `0xc0e2044 0x18e4f899` looks in the right place to be the previous `lr`.  Two words above the lr pushed by `voidFunction` (which pushed two registers including `lr`), and five words below what you've identified as the `lr` of `calcDiff`s caller (and `calcDiff` pushes five registers).  Is there a reason to believe that's not it?